# Click event does not work in the appbar button

Tags: c#, onclick

My app has a appbar 2 button, the click event for the first button works, but not for the second (does not enter the event). Following code:

```
private void AddTipoDespesa_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ucFlyoutAddTipoDespesa fatd = new ucFlyoutAddTipoDespesa();
        fatd.Show();
    }

 <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="barBottom" LostFocus="barBottom_LostFocus">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Button x:Name="addConta" Content="Add Conta"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Adiciona nova conta" Click="addConta_Click" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>

            <Button Name="AddTipoDespesa" Content="Add Tipo Despesa" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Adiciona novo tipo de despesa" Click="AddTipoDespesa_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

The project is a app for windows 8, I'm using vs2012.

Comment: your second button doesn't have x:Name - isn't it a problem?

Comment: The problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

Does the event AddTipoDespesa_Click excist? Otherwise try the event addConta_Click also to the 2nd button. If this works you need to check AddTipoDespesa_Click

Comment: I tried that proposed, still with the problem. I believe this indicates that my UI is wrong. But what would it be?